# JKS missing the private key

Tags: java, keystore

I manage a site www.abc.com which already has a SSL certificate which is expiring in 2 weeks. So I created a .CSR from the existing .JKS file and sent it to the CA. I got back a .PEM and imported the pem file to the existing jks and deleted the old certificate in jks.

When I installed the new jks in web logic server 10.3.6 it threw exception saying the keystore does not have the private key. What would have caused this? Deleting the old certificate using its alias would have deleted the private key as well? Is there a way to check the validity of jks before installing it?

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the old certificate caused the private key to be deleted, recreated the JKS and worked just fine.